# JavaScript code doesn't work in wp contact forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contact-form

I have a javascript code that calculates the distance between two locations. My code is running perfectly with **live server**, WordPress element **HTML** elements and etc. But when I try to put this code into the WordPress contact form plugin it gives me an **error** like this:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: distance_in_kilo is not defined".

This is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  const getKm = document.querySelector('#kilometers');
  // add input listeners
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    var from_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('from_places'));
    var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('to_places'));
    google.maps.event.addListener(from_places, 'place_changed', function() {
      var from_place = from_places.getPlace();
      var from_address = from_place.formatted_address;
      $('#origin').val(from_address);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(to_places, 'place_changed', function() {
      var to_place = to_places.getPlace();
      var to_address = to_place.formatted_address;
      $('#destination').val(to_address);
    });
  });
  // calculate distance
  function calculateDistance() {
    var origin = $('#origin').val();
    var destination = $('#destination').val();
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destination],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      //unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
  }
  // get distance results
  function callback(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      $('#result').html(err);
    } else {
      var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
      var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
      if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
        $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between " + origin + " and " + destination);
      } else {
        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
        var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
        console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
        var distance_in_kilo = distance.value / 1000;
        var distance_in_mile = distance.value / 1609.34;
        var duration_text = duration.text;
        var duration_value = duration.value;
        $('#in_mile').text(distance_in_mile.toFixed(2));
        $('#in_kilo').text(distance_in_kilo.toFixed(2));
        $('#duration_text').text(duration_text);
        $('#duration_value').text(duration_value);
        $('#from').text(origin);
        $('#to').text(destination);
      }
    }
  }
  // print results on submit the form
  $('#distance_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateDistance();
  });
  calculateDistance();
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootstrap-css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Calculate the Distance Between two Addresses demo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="distance_form">
        <div class="form-group"><label>Origin: </label> <input class="form-control" id="from_places" placeholder="Enter a location" /> <input id="origin" name="origin" required="" type="hidden" /></div>
        <div class="form-group"><label>Destination: </label> <input class="form-control" id="to_places" placeholder="Enter a location" /> <input id="destination" name="destination" required="" type="hidden" /></div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Hesapla" /></div>
      <div id="result">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Distance In Mile : <span id='in_kilo'></span> </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Distance is Kilo:</li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">IN TEXT:</li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">IN MINUTES:</li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">FROM:</li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">TO:</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=my_api" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome! A couple questions to clarify: Does the error message come with any additional information - for example about the line number or exact place in the code?
And what do you mean by "put this code into the WordPress contact form plugin". Does the plugin have an area for JavaScript code? Are you sure it's for JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you! This is the error that came up: "(index): 565 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" and this is the code line with the error: "  `var distance_in_kilo = distance.value / 1000;` ". Yes, this plugin allows writing javascript code in it. My goal is to create a user form and calculate the distance between the two selected locations and send it to the admin mail account as an e-mail. I'm trying to do this with plugins because I have no knowledge of php.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a little. Unfortunately, I don't know the Distance Matrix API well enough. But since the error says "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" it basically says that the "distance" variable is undefined. Which means this line results in a value of "undefined": `response.rows[0].elements[0].distance`. Is it possible the script is executed before the user selected any location? You could try to add another `else if` to your conditional doing something like this: `else if(!response.rows[0].elements[0].distance) { return $('#result').html("Please select a location") }`